# Imports friends from gmail and send them a message

Tags: java, android, gmail

i am working on app that send an invitation to user. i already post a message on friends facebook wall but now i wish to send invite to gmail user too

i want to perform following task from my app.

1. Import all contact from my gmail
2. Select all of them and send them a message with download link of my app.

i follow [This Tutorial](http://android10.org/index.php/articlessecuritypermissions/313-implementing-google-oauth-in-android) but with the help of this i just can import friends it not allow me to select all of them and send them message with download link of my app

need guidance from my seniors. May my question rate as duplicated or closed but i didn't fine any useful material from internet.

Regards!

Adnan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/), it is a link to their contacts API. Especially on the section titled: [Retrieving all contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts). The sections below this one may help also, they are titled Retrieving contacts using query parameters, and Retrieving a single contact.

Comment: John Kane it will describe only managing your contact but i want to select of of my imported friends like check box and the send email to selected friends

Comment: then you have to display your contact in a listview with checkboxes and proceed

Comment: There is a section titled: Retrieving all contacts are you sure that this cannot help?

Comment: You would still need to make the ui and implement the checkboxes and backend functionality that you need, but it looks like you should be able to get all of the given users contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample to get all gmail contacts [Sample link](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-oauth-full-example-with-source.html) and there you can post messages to them using their mail IDs

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested in this, I don't recommend using Google OAuth 2.0 API in Android. It's a lot of work to do, and is intended for a general solution to all web/mobile apps.

I think Google Invites API is exactly what's needed here, check [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-grow-your-audience-with-google-app-invites--cms-25321).